# Cached response times from Google Public DNS slow

Tags: domain-name-system, dig, opendns, google-public-dns

I noticed very strange but consistent performance behavior from **Google Public DNS** `8.8.8.8`. Even-though a DNS record was cached, the response time was in the range of `20-30ms`, which seems high. When I switched over to **OpenDNS**, cached response times dived down to `1ms`. Needless to say just made the switch on all the servers to OpenDNS. Can anybody explain this poor performance behavior from Google Public DNS?

Here is the output from **dig** for each test case:

## Google Public DNS

### Uncached (389ms)

```
➜  ~  dig @8.8.8.8 commando.io

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 commando.io
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 655
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;commando.io.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
commando.io.        300 IN  A   192.241.225.51

;; Query time: 389 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 22 12:08:37 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45
```

### Cached (24ms)

```
➜  ~  dig @8.8.8.8 commando.io

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 commando.io
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55425
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;commando.io.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
commando.io.        295 IN  A   192.241.225.51

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 22 12:08:42 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45
```

## OpenDNS

### Uncached (46ms)

```
➜  ~  dig commando.io 

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> commando.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49578
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;commando.io.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
commando.io.        300 IN  A   192.241.225.51

;; Query time: 46 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 22 12:09:43 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45
```

### Cached (1ms)

```
➜  ~  dig commando.io

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> commando.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42532
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;commando.io.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
commando.io.        273 IN  A   192.241.225.51

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 22 12:10:10 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has to do with proximity more than anything else - a response time of 1ms indicates that the OpenDNS server you're hitting is extremely close to your system from a routing perspective.

How do the DNS query times compare to the raw round trip times (ping)?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but if the record is cached, shouldn't it never hit the external DNS server? Your right though, pinging `8.8.8.8` is around `20ms`, while pinging `208.67.222.222` is `1ms`.

Comment: By "external DNS server", are you referring to the recursive DNS server that you're querying (OpenDNS / Google), or are you referring to the authoritative DNS server for the `commando.io` domain?

Comment: It is my understanding that when a DNS record is cached according to the TTL, a request does not need to hit the external DNS server (Google/OpenDNS).

Comment: @Justin That's only if the client system is caching.  `dig` is not interested in using a cache if there is one (which there probably isn't on that system - is `nscd` running?) - it's specifically for sending remote queries.

Comment: But with **dig** if I keep hitting it, I'll see the TTL go down until `0`, then the next time I query dig, the response jumps back to around `50ms`. Then for 5 minutes again, the response time is `1ms`.

Comment: @Justin OpenDNS and Google are caching the response from the authoritative name server.  With the initial request, the recursive resolver you're using (OpenDNS/Google) has no entry in its cache, so they must send the query to the authoritative server (causing the rather slow response).  For subsequent requests, the OpenDNS/Google server has the entry in ***its*** cache, so it responds to you directly without querying the authoritative server.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Makes total sense now. The switch to **OpenDNS** is staying, better performance, probably because they have an anycast node in my DC.

Comment: @Justin Yup, 1ms is almost certainly same building.  Glad to help!